# fatal Error: iostream: No such file or directory - Can you help fix this?

Tags: c++

I have been trying to understand why this sample code will not work in my C++ compiler. I am using Code::Blocks and my main.cpp program works but in the same source, I have another sample program in there called if_else.c (as it automatically named the '.c' part by itself.) Here is the sample code I placed in there:

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()                           
{

 int age;                            

cout<<"Please input your age: ";    
cin>> age;                          
cin.ignore();                       
if ( age < 100 ) {                 
   cout<<"You are pretty young!\n"; 
}
else if ( age == 100 ) {            // I use else just to show an example
cout<<"You are old\n";           // Just to show you it works...
}
else {
cout<<"You are really old\n";     // Executed if no other statement is
}
cin.get();
}
```

Now, every time I go to build the code, I get this error:

"fatal error: iostream: no such file or directory.

Now I am new to C++ coding as I have been using LabVIEW. I understand my path in my compiler settings may be wrong under the "Toolchain Executable" but it seems to be okay.

If there is anything you suggest, I am all ears.

Comment: Rename the file to ".cpp", ".cxx" or tell the compiler to compile as C++.

Answer (score 2):

You have saved your file as `.c`. So the compiler tries to compile it as a C code. Renaming it to `.cpp` will make the compiler compile it as a C++ code.

Comment: Where could I save it as a .cpp? I created as an "empty file" and it seems to automatically create it as a .c. Would it be best if I just re-save it in a .cpp format?

Comment: @KiraCorbett: Ya that would suffice

Answer (score 1):

Save your code with .cpp extension as sometimes the extension is .c, so it shows this error.

file-> save file as... -> filename.cpp