# How to run c++ program in codeblocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

i write a simple progrum in c++ and run using codeblocks(13:12). My code looks like -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "hello" << end1;
    return 0;
}
```

but it's don't build. it gives me an error message .

```
s Mine\c++ pro. . . 1   fetal error: No such file or directory
```

Why i am getting this issue ? Why the iostram file don't found . Whats the wrong with it and how to solve it ?

Comment: You should take more care in typing in your question. For a start, it's `endl` rather than `end1`, and the other spelling mistakes seriously lowers our confidence in what you have shown us.

Comment: You should copy the errors in exactly and not retype them.  fetal error is nonsense.

Comment: It's a problem with iostream import. Please check:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294488/fatal-error-iostream-no-such-file-or-directory-can-you-help-fix-this

Comment: @PaulRooney What if his unborn son is faulty?

Comment: Thanks all , i got the solve . Again thanks for helping

Comment: @JanNilsFerner that is pretty funny and not funny.

Comment: @Mr.goosberry  ??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the error you wrote, but I think that your compiler might not be installed. I suggest you to unistall CodeBlocks and re-download the installer from http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26 that has the compiler already installed: codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe from the link. 
Good luck, pal!

EDIT 1: The script is fine, don't worry about it.

EDIT 2: Oops, I now see that you have a fault in your code. It's endl, not end1!

Comment: Is the script fine? Since when is there a `std::end1` (read as `end one`)?

Comment: Since when is a C++ program called a "script"